# Warning message: garbage collection of typo3

Tags: apache, typo3-flow

Strange things happened

```
Session: Ommitting garbage collection because another process is 
already running. Consider lowering the GC propability if these 
messages appear a lot.
```

Does anyone can explain this warning log ? What is the problems ?

Answer (score 1):

It means that two concurrent requests triggered a session garbage collection. This is nothing bad per se. If this log entry just occured once or twice, that was just the luck of the odds. Else depending on the traffic of your site, the default of 1% probability (ie. every 100th requests on average triggers a garbage collection) might just be too high and you end up with many of these log messages (and wasted cpu cycles).
In that case you should consider reducing the setting **TYPO3.Flow.session.garbageCollection.probability** to something lower, maybe start with "0.1" meaning every 1000th request will trigger the garbage collection.

In case your session storage (default *Data\Temporary\{Context}\Cache\Data\Flow_Session_Storage*) keeps growing up afterwards, you need to increase the **maximumPerRun** setting, so the garbage collection can keep up with the amount of sessions your page creates. That is very unlikely to happen though.